# Unable to create database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have Microsoft SOL Server 2008 R2 on my server. When I am trying to open SOL Server Management Studio as administrator and creating new database, I get this error message

> create database permission denied in database 'master' error 262

Also when I am adding sysadmin in login property window section in my login. Then this message appeared:

> add member failed for server role 'sysadmin'

Please let me know how to add admin permission on my login and easily to create database

Answer (score 0):

you need to login with *SQL server authenticaton* for craeting DataBase.
If you are using **Windows Authentication**  then you need to run SQL server as ***Run As Adminstrator***  to avoid this error.

Further details Here [People Having similar error](http://silverbling.blogspot.in/2009/07/resolving-create-database-permission.html)

Comment: i have opened my ssms as run as adminstrator but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

Login to your workstation as an `administrator` and execute the following query

```
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'Domain\User', 'sysadmin';
```

[CheckHere](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186320.aspx)

`Sql Server` will not consider if you are admin to your workstation ,but you have to explicitly 
make user as a `sysadmin`.

[Intresting](http://prognuggets.blogspot.in/2011/05/resetting-sa-password-for-sql-server.html)